# Why I get Unable to create converter exception from retrofit?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

My problem is, when I use Call inside my retrofit api, I get this exception:

Unable to create converter for retrofit2.Call<java.util.List>
for method IntegApi.getAllProductBarcodeAsync

The intersting thing, if I don't use Call then the error message is gone.

I want to use Call, becuse I would like to use a custom response class, because i want the know when the api sends 404 status, and then I want to skip this exception.

I use Moshi to convert Json

```
Sync function: 
    private suspend fun syncProductBarcodes() {
        try {
            val productBarcodes = api.getAllProductBarcodeAsync().await()
            
            if(productBarcodes.isSuccessful) {
                productBarcodeRepository.deleteAndInsertAll(productBarcodes.body() ?: emptyList())
                addOneToStep()
            }
        }catch (e: Exception){
            Timber.d(e)
            throw e
        }
    }

Api: 
    @GET("Product/GetAllBarcode")
    suspend fun getAllProductBarcodeAsync(): Call<List<ProductBarcode>>

Entity class: 
@Entity(
    tableName = ProductBarcode.TABLE_NAME
)
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
class ProductBarcode(
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    @Json(name = "Id")
    val id: String = "",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "product_id", index = true)
    @Json(name = "ProductId")
    var ProductId: String = "",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "barcode", index = true)
    @Json(name = "Barcode")
    var barcode: String = ""
) {
    companion object {

        const val TABLE_NAME = "product_barcode"
    }
}

ExtensionFun: 
suspend fun <T> Call<T>.await(): Response<T> = suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
    val callback = object : Callback<T> {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<T>, t: Throwable) {
            continuation.resumeWithException(t)
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<T>, response: Response<T>) =
            continuation.resumeNormallyOrWithException {
                if (response.isSuccessful || response.code() == 404) {
                    return@resumeNormallyOrWithException response
                } else {
                    throw IllegalStateException("Http error ${response.code()}, request:${request().url()}")
                }
            }
    }
    enqueue(callback)
}

ApiModule:
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideMoshi(): Moshi {
        return Moshi.Builder()
            .add(DateConverter())
            .add(BigDecimalConverer())
            .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
            .build()
    }

fun provideIntegApi(
        @Named("base_url") url: String, moshi: Moshi,
        prefManager: PrefManager
    ): IntegApi {

        var builder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        builder = BuildTypeInitializations.setupInterceptor(builder)

        builder.addInterceptor { chain ->
            val request = chain.request().newBuilder()
                .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer ${prefManager.token}")
                .addHeader("Connection", "close")
                .build()

            val response = chain.proceed(request)

            return@addInterceptor response
        }
            .readTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .writeTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .connectTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)

        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(url)
            .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())
            .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
            .client(builder.build())
            .build()
            .create(IntegApi::class.java)
    }
```

I don't know exactly why, but If the Api send 404 response, after than I get the Unable to crate converter exception, but I the server send the response, the error message is gone.

Update:

If is use this :

```
    @get:GET("Product/GetAllBarcode")
    val getAllProductBarcodeAsync: Call<List<ProductBarcode>>
```

instead of this:

```
   @GET("Product/GetAllBarcode")
    suspend fun getAllProductBarcodeAsync(): Call<List<ProductBarcode>>
```

There won't be error, and everything works fine, but I don't understand what's the problem

Update2
I changed Moshi to Jackson, and it doesn't throw converter error like moshi, but throw Http 404 Error which is more friendlier for me, but I' m not completely satisfied. I created await() fun because of Http 404 errors, and I think this bunch of code skipped because of http 404?

Comment: Can you try to change your Call extension function signature as inline fun<reified T>...

Comment: I don't think so this will help, because I get the same error, If I use retrofit built in await() method

Comment: Generic types only available during the compile time because compiler will change the generics with their respective real values. So, at the run time, there is no T value for converter to reach and with reified keyword you make the generics usable at runtime. I guess this is the reason why converter could not be created.

Comment: I changed the fun, but I get the same error
Updated fun: 
```suspend inline fun <reified T> Call<T>.await(): Response<T> = suspendCoroutine { continuation ->```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found the issue, I made a mistake, because I tried to use  suspend fun and retrofit Call at the same time. I deleted the suspend keyword, and it works perfectly.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know why removing `suspend` makes it work?

Comment: The `suspend` keyword for interface functions picks up extension functions provided by Retrofit. These extension functions actually just create a `Call` and execute it inside of a coroutine. So, when you define the interface function to return a type wrapped in `Call` the extension function attempts to wrap this inside another `Call`. Essentially the return type becomes `Call<Call<T?>` and Retrofit doesn't understand how to deserialize it.

https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit2/KotlinExtensions.kt